# wxPython: Calculator won't display value in Textctrlenter

Tags: python, wxpython

I am working on a Calculator using wxPyhton. I'm having trouble on displaying the value in a Textctrlenter.

```
self.nameTxt = wx.TextCtrl( self, wx.ID_ANY,"",pos=(10,20),size=(260,30))

self.clickcount1 = 1
one = self.clickcount1

getBtn = wx.Button(self, self.clickcount1,label="1",pos=(10,60),size(40,40))
btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, lambda btnClick, temp=button_name: 
self.OnButton(btnClick(1), temp) )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `lamba` function is incorrect.
The `size(40,40)` parameter in getBtn, should be `size=(40,40)`
The `Bind` should be on `getBtn` not `btn`
The variable `one` is not used at all
You're using `self.clickcount` as the button `id`, don't, use `-1` or `wx.ID_ANY` and wxpython will generate a unique id for you.
I assume that you are trying to do something like this:

```
import wx

class TestFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args)
        self.nameTxt = wx.TextCtrl( self, wx.ID_ANY,"",pos=(10,20),size=(260,30))
        getBtn1 = wx.Button(self, id=-1, label="1", pos=(10,60), size=(40,40))
        getBtn1.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, lambda event: self.OnButton(event, button=1) )
        getBtn2 = wx.Button(self, id=-1, label="2", pos=(50,60), size=(40,40))
        getBtn2.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, lambda event: self.OnButton(event, button=2) )
        getBtn3 = wx.Button(self, id=-1, label="3", pos=(90,60), size=(40,40))
        getBtn3.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, lambda event: self.OnButton(event, button=3) )
        self.Show()

    def OnButton(self, event, button):
        print ("Button number ", button)
        curr_value = self.nameTxt.GetValue()
        # If a value exists add to it, otherwise display value of pressed button
        try:
            curr_value = int(curr_value) + button
            self.nameTxt.SetValue(str(curr_value))
        except:
            self.nameTxt.SetValue(str(button))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    myframe = TestFrame(None, -1, "Calculator Test")
    app.MainLoop()
```

[image]

With regard to your comment about wanting "11111111":
change the function `OnButton` to:

```
def OnButton(self, event, button):
    print ("Button number ", button)
    curr_value = self.nameTxt.GetValue()
    curr_value = curr_value + str(button)
    self.nameTxt.SetValue(curr_value)
```

Comment: Thank you Rolf of Saxony for giving suggestion.

Comment: Hello i am trying to press one btn like 10 time's it display (1111111111) like this thank you

Comment: Hello Rolf of Saxony i tried to execute the code but it showing that Typing Error: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Comment: @vinaydoddapaneni Use `curr_value = curr_value + str(button)` not `curr_value = curr_value + button`

Comment: Hello Rolf of Saxony i am looking for addition for example take a sample calculator first press  button "one" "+" "2" "=" then it have to show the answer thank you once again.

Comment: Attaching additional questions to a question on StackOverflow is frowned upon. The reason being that each question should stand on its own merit and address a specific issue. This allows others with a similar problem to search for and find answers for it. You should ask a new question, specifying your problem and any code that you have tried so far.